# Explanation of state replication of barrelfish

Tags: operating-system, kernel, replication, multicore

Can you tell how the Barrelfish OS is implementing the state replication of its kernel on each each core or closely-coupled "shared" on cores in case e have a multi or many cores chip.
As I am trying to understand this point, even I tried to check the source code, no more documentation explain this process of spawning kernel over the whole cores.

And if you can offer me a way to understand the source code of this part will be great as I really try to trace the source code, but looks like I swim a lone in the ocean.

Thanks a lot.
Abdo~

Comment: try the mailing list :-- http://lists.inf.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/barrelfish-users  Barrel fish is a research OS ... I really doubt if the SO community has many experts on it... I had read their paper as  part of my OS course but haven't used it as such... But very soon I will be running barrel fish in a VM and analyzing its non-determinism .... my project is in the kvm hypervisor. What are you working on ?? Why do need barrelfish OS for ???

Comment: @Deepthought, I am interestd in knowing what are working on using barrelfish, me stil l stuck in memory TLB understanding but feeling that didn't do much effort yet

Comment: Well, I don't have to touch any part of the code(atleast I hope :) ). I will be running Barrelfish in a VM, record all its non determinism and then replay it. I am working on multiprocessor record replay, through the work that we have done till now using gentoo in VM we have realized that more the non-determinism slower the record replay. We want to find out how good a OS like Barrel fish which is meant for multicore will perform for a record replay

Comment: Lucky you I have to play with this code, good luck anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

One example for state replication in Barrelfish is the capability system [1, especially section 5]. Every core (in fact, every dispatcher) has their own storage for capabilities. Many operations can be done locally, without synchronizing with other cores. If synchronization is needed, the capability system helps us to find all replicas, since copy operations to other cores are explicit and can be tracked.

The Barrelfish source code is probably not the place to further look into this, since our capability system is quite complex.

If you have further questions, please refer to our mailing list [2] as suggested by Deepthought

[1] http://www.barrelfish.org/TN-013-CapabilityManagement.pdf
[2] http://lists.inf.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/barrelfish-users

Comment: Briefly, I am trying to work on the barrelfish two parts:
First: I want to play around with the TLB, and the current implementation of virtual memory for my MPhil as I am very new to this area of computation,

Second, I want to know exactly how does it work this state replication as what will happen when trying to control the resources in case I want to span set of cores as a one VM?